# Sliding navigation with half screen

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation, android-animation

i want to create one screen for my android application in this application i want to create sliding navigation feature which is full visible on swipe (Left to Right ) and when user again swipe (RIght to Left ) it again swipe and close navigation window half and display half screen , i have used navigation drawer but i am not aware with this so please some help me  if you have any code so please send me its will be my pleasure .
i am sending one image for reference where .
[image: required screen closed in red rectangle]

Comment: what you have tried ? Post the code.

Answer (score 1):

Find below code create a class AnimationLayout

```
    import usb.terminal.R;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.util.AttributeSet;
    import android.view.MotionEvent;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.view.animation.Animation;
    import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;

    public class AnimationLayout extends ViewGroup {

    public final static int DURATION = 1000;

    protected boolean mPlaceLeft = true;
    public boolean mOpened;
    protected View mSidebar;
    protected View mContent;
    protected int mSidebarWidth = 100; /*
                                         * assign default value. It will be
                                         * overwrite in onMeasure by Layout xml
                                         * resource.
                                         */
    protected Animation mAnimation;
    protected OpenListener mOpenListener;
    protected CloseListener mCloseListener;
    protected Listener mListener;

    protected boolean mPressed = false;

    public AnimationLayout(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public AnimationLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();
        mSidebar = findViewById(R.id.animation_layout_sidebar);
        mContent = findViewById(R.id.animation_layout_content);

        if (mSidebar == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("no view id = animation_sidebar");
        }

        if (mContent == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("no view id = animation_content");
        }

        mOpenListener = new OpenListener(mSidebar, mContent);
        mCloseListener = new CloseListener(mSidebar, mContent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        /* the title bar assign top padding, drop it */
        int sidebarLeft = l;
        if (!mPlaceLeft) {
            sidebarLeft = r - mSidebarWidth;
        }
        mSidebar.layout(sidebarLeft, 0, sidebarLeft + mSidebarWidth,
                0 + mSidebar.getMeasuredHeight());

        if (mOpened) {
            if (mPlaceLeft) {
                mContent.layout(l + mSidebarWidth, 0, r + mSidebarWidth, b);
            } else {
                mContent.layout(l - mSidebarWidth, 0, r - mSidebarWidth, b);
            }
        } else {
            mContent.layout(l, 0, r, b);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int w, int h) {
        super.onMeasure(w, h);
        super.measureChildren(w, h);
        mSidebarWidth = mSidebar.getMeasuredWidth();
    }

    @Override
    protected void measureChild(View child, int parentWSpec, int parentHSpec) {
        /* the max width of Sidebar is 90% of Parent */
        if (child == mSidebar) {
            int mode = MeasureSpec.getMode(parentWSpec);
            int width = (int) (getMeasuredWidth() * 0.9);
            super.measureChild(child, MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(width, mode),
                    parentHSpec);
        } else {
            super.measureChild(child, parentWSpec, parentHSpec);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        if (!isOpening()) {
            return false;
        }

        int action = ev.getAction();

        if (action != MotionEvent.ACTION_UP
                && action != MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            return false;
        }

        /*
         * if user press and release both on Content while sidebar is opening,
         * call listener. otherwise, pass the event to child.
         */
        int x = (int) ev.getX();
        int y = (int) ev.getY();
        if (mContent.getLeft() < x && mContent.getRight() > x
                && mContent.getTop() < y && mContent.getBottom() > y) {
            if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                mPressed = true;
            }

            if (mPressed && action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP
                    && mListener != null) {
                mPressed = false;
                return mListener.onContentTouchedWhenOpening();
            }
        } else {
            mPressed = false;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public void setListener(Listener l) {
        mListener = l;
    }

    /* to see if the Sidebar is visible */
    public boolean isOpening() {
        return mOpened;
    }

    public void toggleSidebar() {
        if (mContent.getAnimation() != null) {
            return;
        }

        if (mOpened) {
            /* opened, make close animation */
            if (mPlaceLeft) {
                mAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(0, -mSidebarWidth, 0, 0);
            } else {
                mAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(0, mSidebarWidth, 0, 0);
            }
            mAnimation.setAnimationListener(mCloseListener);
        } else {
            /* not opened, make open animation */
            if (mPlaceLeft) {
                mAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(0, mSidebarWidth, 0, 0);
            } else {
                mAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(0, -mSidebarWidth, 0, 0);
            }
            mAnimation.setAnimationListener(mOpenListener);
        }
        mAnimation.setDuration(DURATION);
        mAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
        mAnimation.setFillEnabled(true);
        mContent.startAnimation(mAnimation);
    }

    public void openSidebar() {
        if (!mOpened) {
            toggleSidebar();
        }
    }

    public void closeSidebar() {
        if (mOpened) {
            toggleSidebar();
        }
    }

    class OpenListener implements Animation.AnimationListener {
        View iSidebar;
        View iContent;

        OpenListener(View sidebar, View content) {
            iSidebar = sidebar;
            iContent = content;
        }

        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }

        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            iSidebar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            iContent.clearAnimation();
            mOpened = !mOpened;
            requestLayout();
            if (mListener != null) {
                mListener.onSidebarOpened();
            }
        }
    }

    class CloseListener implements Animation.AnimationListener {
        View iSidebar;
        View iContent;

        CloseListener(View sidebar, View content) {
            iSidebar = sidebar;
            iContent = content;
        }

        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }

        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        }

        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            iContent.clearAnimation();
            iSidebar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            mOpened = !mOpened;
            requestLayout();
            if (mListener != null) {
                mListener.onSidebarClosed();
            }
        }
    }

    public interface Listener {
        public void onSidebarOpened();

        public void onSidebarClosed();

        public boolean onContentTouchedWhenOpening();
    }
}
```

create a mainlayout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
      >

        <yourpackage..AnimationLayout
            android:id="@+id/animation_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
      <!--Create you Layout which you want and just call in this include-->
            <include
                android:id="@id/animation_layout_sidebar"
                android:layout_width="470dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                layout="@layout/my_cook_menu"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
            </include>
      <!--Create you Layout which you want and just call in this include-->
            <include
                android:id="@id/animation_layout_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                layout="@layout/sound_my_cook"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
            </include>
        </yourpackage.AnimationLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

create id.xml in values folder

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <resources>
 <item type="id" name="animation_layout_sidebar" />
 <item type="id" name="animation_layout_content" />
 </resources>
```

write this code in which activity you are calling

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
         AnimationLayout.Listener, OnClickListener{
    AnimationDrawable frameAnimation;
    AnimationLayout animationLayout;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.mainlayout);


    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
          try {
                    animationLayout = (AnimationLayout) findViewById(R.id.animation_layout);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                animationLayout.toggleSidebar();
      }

       @Override
       public void onSidebarOpened() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

       }

      @Override
      public void onSidebarClosed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

      }

      @Override
      public boolean onContentTouchedWhenOpening() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it yet but I think **DrawerLayout** recently added to support library could give you what you need. [Here is the link for documentation.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html) This is something what Facebook app is using to slide a pannel from left to right. [Here is the tutorial.](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html)